# How to pass Before Date and End Date to Dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I was playing around with a way to dynamically pass begin and end dates to a query.  I got this far, and got stuck.

```
Declare @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date
Select @StartDate = '01/01/2018', @EndDate = '01/01/2020'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL1 varchar(5000)

    SELECT @SQL1=' Select RCA.[IDRSSD],
       POR.Institution,
       POR.Filing_Type,
       RCA.Schedule_Code,
       Map.Call_Report,
       RCA.Line_Item,
       RCA.Code,
       Right(RCA.Code,4) As Harmonized_Code,
       Q.QuarterEnd, Q.Amount as Amount
From [RCA] As RCA
INNER JOIN [POR] As POR
ON RCA.IDRSSD = POR.IDRSSD
INNER JOIN Mapping As Map
ON RCA.Schedule_Code = Map.Schedule_Code
CROSS APPLY
(
VALUES
(''2019Q4'',RCA.[2019Q4]),
(''2019Q3'',RCA.[2019Q3]),
(''2019Q2'',RCA.[2019Q2]),
(''2019Q1'',RCA.[2019Q1]),
(''2018Q4'',RCA.[2018Q4]),
(''2018Q3'',RCA.[2018Q3])
) AS Q(QuarterEnd,Amount) 
Where Q.QuarterEnd BETWEEN ''' + Convert(Varchar(10), @StartDate, 101) +''' and '''+ Convert(Varchar(10), @EndDate, 101) + ''''

Print(@SQL1) 
EXEC (@SQL1)
End
```

The thing that I am stuck on, is that the quarter-end dates are headers/columns, and not dates listed in a column of dates.  Here is a screen shot of one table.

[image]

Here is my DDL and DML.

```
--TABLE1
--DROP TABLE POR
CREATE TABLE POR
( IDRSSD varchar(10),
  Institution  VARCHAR(100),
  Filing_Type int)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53540', 'Wells', 3)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53550', 'BofA', 1)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53560', 'Chase', 2)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53570', 'JPM', 4)

--TABLE2
--DROP TABLE RCA
CREATE TABLE RCA
( IDRSSD varchar(10),
  Schedule_Code  VARCHAR(10),
  Line_Item varchar(100),
  Code varchar(10),
  [2019Q4] varchar(10),
  [2019Q3] varchar(10),
  [2019Q2] varchar(10),
  [2019Q1] varchar(10),
  [2018Q4] varchar(10),
  [2018Q3] varchar(10))

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53540', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '127000', '146000', '9370', '1000', '1300', '12000')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53540', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '4390', '8220', '7570', '9800', '11230', '15570')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53560', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '14390', '8220', '700', '4800', '1230', '57')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53560', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '9000', '2200', '5700', '980', '300', '5570')

--TABLE3
--DROP TABLE Mapping
CREATE TABLE Mapping
( Schedule_Code varchar(10),
  Call_Report  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RC', 'Balance Sheet')
INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RCA', 'Cash and Balances')
INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RCB', 'Securities')
```

Comment: the `QuarterEnd ` are string like `2019Q4`, so your dates `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` should be varchar too. Also you should use `sp_executesql`, you will be able to pass in the dates as parameter

Comment: I made those changes, and when I re-ran the code, I got this error message: Incorrect syntax near ')'. So, I double-clicked on that error message, and it highlighted this: Print(@SQL1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how the changes would be

Change the @StartDate and @EndDate to varchar

```
Declare @StartDate varchar(10), @EndDate varchar(10)
Select @StartDate = '2018Q1', @EndDate = '2018Q4'
```

Since it is varchar, you don't need to convert before concatenation

```
) AS Q(QuarterEnd,Amount) 
Where Q.QuarterEnd BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate'
```

use `sp_executesql` and pass in the @StartDate and @EndDate as parameter

```
exec sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@StartDate varchar(10), @EndDate varchar(10)', @StartDate, @EndDate
```

Also change the `@SQL` to `nvarchar(max)`. `sp_executesql` expects a `nvarchar`

```
DECLARE @SQL1 nvarchar(max)
```